# Is JCE needed if you have LDAP?

Tags: java, ldap, jce

Do you need to have JCE embedded in your Java application when you already have LDAP authentication in place?

Comment: You are going to need to elaborate a little.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: LDAP is for authentication and user details. JCE is for cryptography. There isn't much overlap. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

I believe it depends on what kind of authentication you're doing with the LDAP server.